# Write short stories before your main story to help the worldbuilding process

Tags: worldbuilding-process, universe

Is it good worldbuilding practice to write short stories happening in your universe to set a precedent to how your world works and how the common and always unseen characters would find their way around the realm?

For example, you write a short story or situation of any member of society, to give yourself a good impression of how the background of each place works.

The protests of a peasant against the water consumption of the factory up the river, the report of a captain about an encounter with pirates, the letter of a mayor to the supreme sorcerer to ask for more troops to protect against the yearly invasion of demons, etc.

Could you give 4 or 5 more examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### YES and NO

Okay, allow me to blow off some steam before answering. As a writer, I experienced numerous occasions when this suggestion was brought up. Unfortunately, most of the time this comes from the mouth of self-indulgent authors who consider themselves better than anyone else and it honestly makes them sound more of a smartass than anything. What really pisses me off is that their main critique towards pretty much anyone who tackles writing any sort of larger work is: "Why haven't I read any of your short works in any of the relevant publishing works? Don't bother writing anything large until you're a short-work veteran!"

The answer is: Yes and no. I've written several short stories in my world to see how would things work out, things like background lore stories or mythology that would eventually get mentioned in the passing when the main storyline comes around and, from what I managed to conclude, it works as much to my benefit as to my detriment. I can explore certain concepts and decide later whether I want to incorporate them fully into the storyline or pass them off as obsolete material that once held relevance and got surpassed by a different story further down the timeline, but keeping them short actively prevents me as the author from fully fleshing them out.

Basically, what I'm trying to say is that short stories are always a welcome addition to any world and they can help the worldbuilding process, but ONLY if you already have a solid foundation to build upon. They're an excellent filler when it comes to bringing variety into the franchise, but they should never be intended as building blocks for other storylines or ESPECIALLY as foundation blocks to establish the rules how your world works.

My personal experience is that short stories should be an exception rather than the rule in the worldbuilding process. You can take a throw-away character or a throw-away concept to see how it works out for the sheer fun of it and provide extra depth and detail to your world, but the moment you start building upon them any further these short stories actually stop being short stories and evolve into something more, at that point they have to be refined to fit the rest of the narrative and they cannot be considered short stories any longer.

PS EDIT: Sadly I'm not going to provide any examples from my own works because my storyline is progressing at a snails pace and dropping my short stories out in open waters on the Internet simply isn't in my best interest.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain why yes and why not.
About the stories I was mostly talking about short situations resumed in 1 to 3 phrases to state the situation and some of the inner workings of the world.

I have to admit that I'm finding it difficult to extend them longer than that without narrowing the freedom of the choices of the main character more than how I want it to be.

Comment: Sorry for not being able to respond sooner. If you're talking about stories which can be summized in three paragraphs or less, the term "anecdote" would be a more fitting definition. I'd say the guidelines I stated above should be applied in an even more limiting fashion on anecdotes than short stories because, if short stories are the salt and sugar of worldbuilding, then anecdotes are the exotic spices. Adding just a little bit of them from time to time will enhance the flavor but adding too much could have disastrous consequences for the narrative as a whole.